# Robust graceful shutdown of an application

Tags: c, linux

To ensure that all destructors are properly called if the program is terminated from keyboard (Ctrl+C), the approach with signals are used:

- a handler, which sets an exit flag, is set for SIGINT
- if a blocking call (`accept()`, `read()`, `connect()`, etc) is waiting for completion, it returns -1 and `errno` is set to `EINTR`

The problem is that `SIGINT` can arrive between check for exit flag (`while (!finish)`) and calling `read()`. In this case, `read()` will be blocked until the signal is sent once again.

This is a minimal working example:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR };

static unsigned char finish=0;

static void handleSignal(int signal) {
    finish=1;
}

int main(int argc, char ** e) {
    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
    action.sa_handler=handleSignal;
    action.sa_flags=0;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);
    
    char buffer[256];
    puts("<<");
    while (!finish) {
        sleep(2);
        ssize_t n=read(STDIN, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (n==0) {
            // End of stream
            finish=1;
        }
        else if (n<0) {
            // Error or interrupt
            if (errno!=EINTR)
                perror("read");
        }
        else {
            // Convert data to hexadecimal format
            for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
                printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    puts(">>\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

`sleep(2)` is added for visibility (a real program may perform some preparational work before reading from file descritor).

If there any way of reliable handling of signals without using non-crossplatform things like `signalfd()`?

Comment: Finish needs to be (at least) volatile. Also: google for "pipe trick" And there is always wait() and pause()

Comment: You are already using posix specific functions such as `sigaction` so that makes the code not strictly cross platform anyway. If you can accept posix functions then `signalfd` and/ot `select` would be one solution.

Comment: You can use `select` with say 1s timeout and check for `finish` periodically, only call `read` when data is available.

Comment: @wildplasser [The C standard requires `volatile sig_atomic_t`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p5):  "When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects that are neither lock-free atomic objects nor of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` are unspecified... The value of any object modified by the handler that is neither a lock-free atomic object nor of type `volatile sig_atomic_t` becomes indeterminate when the handler exits"

Comment: That's why I said "at least"

Comment: I think this is what `pselect` is for.  You block the signal, check if it occurred, and then use pselect to atomically unblock it, wait, and reblock.  Is that an option for you?

Comment: @kaylum: I don't think `signalfd` is POSIX, is it?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yeah you're right. So `select` of `pselect` if OP is ok to use posix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  [`pselect(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) system call was invented to solve this exact problem.  It's POSIX, so hopefully cross-platform enough for you.

The purpose of `pselect` is to atomically unblock some signals, wait for I/O as `select()` does, and reblock them.  So your loop can look something like the following pseudocode:

```
sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, {SIGINT});
while (1) {
    if (finish)
        graceful_exit();
    int ret = pselect(1, {STDIN}, ..., { /* empty signal set */});
    if (ret > 0) {
        read(STDIN, buf, size); // will not block
        // process data
        // If you like you can do
        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, {SIGINT});
        // work work work
        if (finish)
            graceful_exit();
        // work work work
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, {SIGINT});
    } else {
        // handle timeout or other errors
    }
}
```

There is no race here because `SIGINT` is blocked for the time in between checking the `finish` flag and the call to `pselect`, so it cannot be delivered during that window.  But the signal is unblocked while `pselect` is waiting, so if it arrives during that time (or already arrived while it was blocked), `pselect` will return without further delay.  We only call `read` when `pselect` has told us it was ready for reading, so it cannot block.

If your program is multithreaded, use `pthread_sigmask` instead of `sigprocmask`.

As was noted in comments, you have to make your `finish` flag volatile, and for best compatibility it should be of type `sig_atomic_t`.

There is more discussion and another example in the [`select_tut(2)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut).